# Adding a search option to search through a list of dictionaries

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

So this is kind of a loaded question

I have a program that stores quotes, the author of the quotes, and the date the quote was said.

In my program the quotes are stored in a list of dictionaries. In each dictionary there are three keys and values, such that:

```
[{'quote':'What the quote is', 'author':'The authors name', 'date':'when it was said}...]
```

Here's where I am stuck...
I want to add an option for the user to be able to enter a search term and then loop through my quotes List of dictionary's and print quotes that contain the search term along with the author and date of the quotes.

so this would be the start of what i'm trying to do:

```
elif choice == 's':
    searchTerm = input('Enter a search term: ')
```

how can i go about this if you get what I'm trying to say?

Comment: So, you want to search with a quote or a string that appears in the quote?

Comment: If your problem is solved, you could accept one of the working answers. This way others know that no further effort is needed to help you.

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
quotes_list = [{'quote':'I am hungry', 'author':'Thomas', 'date':'5 minutes ago'},]

for entry in quotes_list:
    if searchTerm in entry['quote']:
        print('"{}" -- {}; {}'.format(entry['quote'], entry['author'], entry['date']))
```

with `searchTerm = 'hungry'`, for instance, this would result in

```
"I am hungry" -- Thomas; 5 minutes ago
```

Answer (score 0):

If I get what you need correctly, you may want to try this -

```
print [' - '.join(i.values()) for i in quote_list if searchTerm in i['quote']]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
searchTerm = input('Enter a search term: ')
for dict in dict_list:
  if searchTerm in dict['quote']:
    print(dict['quote'] + " - " + dict['author'] + " - " + dict['date'])
    print()
```

Comment: I think it's not a good idea to call a dictionary `dict`, as it is a reserved word.

Comment: you may upvote and tick my answer if you think it is correct